# "small-data section exceeds 64KB.." "additional relocation overflows omitted from the output 1>collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, mips

I am using GCC compiler. After canceling -mno-gpopt flag
I am getting the following error during compilation:

```
 c:/................../ld.exe: small-data section exceeds 64KB;
 lower small-data size limit (see option -G)
 .....................:(.text._ii_sem+0x56): relocation truncated to fit:**** 
 ........................
 ......................(.text._ii_+0x128): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 make: *** [Makefile:76: ps100] Error 1
```

(see option -G) - MIPS documentation

> This option directs the compiler to put definitions of externally-visible data in a small data section when that data is
> no bigger than num bytes. GCC can then use gp-relative addressing, which is a powerful tool for reducing code size
> and is a favorite among toolchain designers. Data that is stored within reach of the gp register can be accessed in a
> single instruction using a signed, 16-bit offset from the gp register ($28). Because the maximum addressing range is
> 64K bytes, the total size of the small data section (.sdata, .sbss , .scommon) should be less than 64K bytes.

What is "small-data section", how can I control its size?
Which data saved in the small section?
What is -g default, i.e. if "num" was not mentioned at the Makefile?

Edit: I have tried to use "-G0" and, I have got the same error. I have checked .o files and didn't found .sbss/.sdata section. Any idea why am I getting the same error?

Answer (score 1):

You may use "-G0" option for compiler. "-G" option setup maximum size of variable in small data section. It would be no data in sbss/sdata/scommon in this case.

Comment: Most likely libraries (libc, libm, ...) are built with -G4 key and its global data is in sbss/sdata sections. Dou compile gcc by yourself or use some prebuilt?